# Android : Error in setcontentview();

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, my layout `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` shows error. I have the `activity_main.xml` under the `resource-> layout` folder. what is wrong??

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Traceback from logcat please

Comment: Please post your activity_main.xml also the error should indicate a line where the issue is...

Comment: may i know the logcat error,what u r getting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if there is a line called `import android R;` , delete that line. 
Next, do this:

1. Clean your project by clicking Project, scroll down, and click Clean.
2. Rebuild your project by again clicking Project, scroll down click Build All.

I'm assuming you are using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have a line called import android.r

Comment: delete that line and then follow the instructions in my answer.